# PHP: How to change PHP_INI_* mode

Tags: php, apache, configuration

I have a question about how to set `PHP_INI_*` modes and where to set them. I found this link about from http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php. It says there are mode `PHP_INI_USER`, `PHP_INI_ALL`, `PHP_INI_SYSTEM`, `PHP_INI_PERDIR`. The user notice above says that Apache have several directives to change `PHP_INI_*` mode configuration, but I can't find these directives in `httpd.conf`. Which Apache configuration files are they in? For example, can I change configuration mode from `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` to `PHP_INI_USER`? How can I do that?

Comment: I think I have a misunderstanding about PHP_INI_* mode. I thought there should be specific directives to change them from one to another. But it seems they are just like property of directives, determine the accessing scopes of directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you can set a php_ini per user or per dir level depends on multiple conditions:

- The **php_ini directive itself**. Refer to the documentation of the specific ini directive to know if it is allowed to set per user or per dir or whatever
- The value of the directive `user_ini.filename` If it is omitted or empty, then setting php_ini directives **per user level** isn't possible. Thats because PHP does not know where to search for that user.ini files
- When in apache conf php_ini directives can be set **per directory** inside a `<directory>` tag, or in a `.htaccess` following the syntax described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php). Also note that the (apache) `AllowOveride` settings for this directories MUST be set to either `AllowOverrideOptions` or `AllowOverrideAll` in order to do so.